# How to get the full name of a Sitecore DMS rule?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore7, sitecore-dms

I'm using Sitecore. I want to get the full name/description of a DMS rule in programcode by Sitecore ID, for example: "Where the DayOfWeek has a value that is equal to Tuesday".

Who knows how to do this?

Thanks a lot.

Jordy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a simple way, but the class responsible for rendering the rule text is `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Rules.RulesRenderer` in `Sitecore.Client.dll`.

Its constructor accepts the XML from a rules field and you call the `Render` method, passing in a prepared `HtmlTexteWriter`. It also has a bunch of fairly self-explanatory private methods like `RenderRule`, `RenderCondition` etc.

I'm sure if you decompile that class you can pick out the bits you need.

Comment: Thank you for your great tip. I decompiled this class, but it is hard to get the DMS rule. Can you help me some?

Comment: do you have access to the rule item in sitecore?

Comment: I know the rules UniqueID, but that isn't a Sitecore ID. So I can't find it in de the content tree. A rule is made up of conditions and actions etc.; it is a composition of this. I want to get the totall rule text.

Comment: Sorry, one more question. How are you obtaining the Unique ID

Comment: I called the Sitecore GetRenderings() method. In the settings object you can find the rules. I figured out that the UniqueID matches the Layout Renderings. When you set raw values on in the Content Editor you can see a xml. I need to query this or is there a special Sitecore method for?

Comment: Another one to decompile:  `Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.InsertRenderings.Personalization` in `Sitecore.Analytics.dll`. Not sure exactly how you're approaching things, but this class seems to implement a few different ways of getting at the rules from a rendering.